# Why call PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg() need to in main UI thread?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I want to call PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg() to decode a image stream, but seemed that I have to call it in main UI thread, otherwise it will raise a "Invalid cross-thread access." exception.

```
Stream imageStream = serivce.GetPicture();
WriteableBitmap bitmap = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(imageStream);
...
```

I must to move it to Dispatcher body as below, and here I think there is no UI Controls involved in my codes, that is why?

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    Stream imageStream = serivce.GetPicture();
    WriteableBitmap bitmap = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(imageStream);
    ...
});
```

Comment: try to use threadStart and write a method returning WriteableBitmap

Comment: What is the line causing the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Nearly everything connected with images should be done in UI thread because of `DispatcherObject` in class hierarchy. This is an issue of Silverlight framework design. Probably guys had lack of time to port WPF properly.